# How to add a custom OpenId Filter in a Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

I am trying to implement the backend side of an OpenId Connect authentication. It is a stateless API so I added a filter that handles the Bearer token.

I have created the OpenIdConnect Filter that handles the Authentication and added it in a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
public class OpenIdConnectFilter extends 
   AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
 @Value("${auth0.clientId}")
 private String clientId;

 @Value("${auth0.issuer}")
 private String issuer;

 @Value("${auth0.keyUrl}")
 private String jwkUrl;

private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();

public OpenIdConnectFilter() {
    super("/connect/**");
    setAuthenticationManager(new NoopAuthenticationManager());
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(OpenIdConnectFilter filter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
  registration.setEnabled(false);
  return registration;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {


    try {
      Authentication authentication = tokenExtractor.extract(request);

      String accessToken = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String kid = JwtHelper.headers(accessToken)
            .get("kid");
        final Jwt tokenDecoded = JwtHelper.decodeAndVerify(accessToken, verifier(kid));
        final Map<String, Object> authInfo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(tokenDecoded.getClaims(), Map.class);
        verifyClaims(authInfo);
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(((String) authInfo.get("scope")).split(" ")));
        int expires = (Integer) authInfo.get("exp");
        OpenIdToken openIdToken = new OpenIdToken(accessToken, scopes, Long.valueOf(expires), authInfo);
        final OpenIdUserDetails user = new OpenIdUserDetails((String) authInfo.get("sub"), "Test", openIdToken);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not obtain user details from token", e);
    }

}

public void verifyClaims(Map claims) {
    int exp = (int) claims.get("exp");
    Date expireDate = new Date(exp * 1000L);
    Date now = new Date();
    if (expireDate.before(now) || !claims.get("iss").equals(issuer) || !claims.get("azp").equals(clientId)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid claims");
    }
}


private RsaVerifier verifier(String kid) throws Exception {
    JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(jwkUrl));
    Jwk jwk = provider.get(kid);
    return new RsaVerifier((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey());
}
```

Here is security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OpenIdConnectWebServerConfig extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public OpenIdConnectFilter myFilter() {
   final OpenIdConnectFilter filter = new OpenIdConnectFilter();
   return filter;
 }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.cors();
  http.antMatcher("/connect/**").authorizeRequests() 
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/connect/public").permitAll()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/connect/private").authenticated()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/connect/private- 
       messages").hasAuthority("read:messages")
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/connect/private- 
      roles").hasAuthority("read:roles")
  .and()
    .addFilterBefore(myFilter(), 
       UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Rest endpoints looks like following:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/connect/public", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
     produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
   public String publicEndpoint() throws JSONException {
    return new JSONObject()
          .put("message", "All good. You DO NOT need to be authenticated to 
         call /api/public.")
          .toString();
  }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/connect/private", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
      produces = "application/json")
     @ResponseBody
     public String privateEndpoint() throws JSONException {
      return new JSONObject()
          .put("message", "All good. You can see this because you are 
     Authenticated.")
          .toString();
```

}

If I remove completely the filter for configuration and also the @Bean definition, the configuration works as expected:  /connect/public is accessible, while /connect/private is forbidden.

If I keep the @Bean definition and add it in filter chain the response returns a Not Found status for requests both on /connect/public and /connect/private:

```
"timestamp": "18.01.2019 09:46:11",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/
```

When debugging I noticed that filter is processing the token and returns an implementation of Authentication.

1. Is the filter properly added in filter chain and in correct position?
2. Why is the filter invoked also on /connect/public path when this is supposed to be public. Is it applied to all paths matching super("/connect/**") call?
3. Why is it returning the path as "/" when the request is made at /connect/private

Seems that is something wrong with the filter, cause every time it is applied, the response is messed up.

Comment: Spring Boot detects all `Filter` implementations and automatically registers them. You add it to the Spring Security filter chain so it is actually invoked twice in the chain. Add an additional `FilterRegistrationBean` in which you disable the filter, this will prevent Spring Boot from adding it to the filter chain and leaves only the one in the Spring Security chain.

Comment: yes, this was a good improvement. Now the filter is invoked much fewer times. But when it is invoked the response is the same. with path: "/". Seems something wrong also with Filter. I have updated the question.

Comment: The filter will always be called, even on the `permitAll` as it is part of the filter chain. Also the fact that your path shows `/` doesn't mean it is wrong. What is behind the `/connect/public` URLs?

Comment: There are two endpoints there. I have updated the question. But if I don't add the filter, the response is as expected.

Comment: So the problem is SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler that redirects to "/" after authentication. This is invoked by AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. If I override that functionality and do myself redirect to url it works fine. Seems it's enough if I override requiresAuthentication and add check that my authentication exists in security context, but it rather sounds like a hack.

Comment: Well not a problem, due to not configuring your filter with actions what to do after authentication it sticks with the defaults. However the defaults should redirect to the requested URL (but due to using OpenID that might change due to the redirects etc. happening). Is there a reason you aren't using the Spring Security OpenID support but rather your own?

Comment: Not really. This is just a poc. But we have a private authentication provider. I just didn't found the proper spring implementation. Is it handled by default in spring-security-oauth2?

Comment: Depends on the version of Spring Security but as of version 5 there is OpenID Connect support.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to have a functional version. So the key was to also overwrite the successfulAuthentication handler.